# Python generator confusing behavior

Tags: python, generator, send, coroutine

This question arises when I read a generator tutorial https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/. `is_palindrome(101)` returns True, but the code didn't print 101. I debugged and saw `yield 101` led the execution back to the main `for` loop, which immediately went back to the generator, which is very confusing. The generator yields 101, hence it should be an element of `for j in pal_gen:`, isn't it?

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    # Skip single-digit inputs
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return False
    temp = num
    reversed_num = 0

    while temp != 0:
        reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10

    if num == reversed_num:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def infinite_palindromes():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(num):
            i = (yield num)
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1

if __name__=='__main__':        
    pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
    for j in pal_gen:
        print(f'j={j}')
        digits = len(str(j))
        if digits == 5:
            pal_gen.close()        
        pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
```

Currently the output is:

```
j=11
j=111
j=1111
j=10101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generator.py", line 33, in <module>
    pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice it is skipping one between each. 101 is missing, 1001 is missing. 10001 is missing. I'm pretty sure `send` leads the generator to run to the next yield statement. For example, use the following code:

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
    for j in pal_gen:
        print('j={}'.format(j))
        digits = len(str(j))
        if digits == 5:
            pal_gen.close()
        print(pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits)))
```

This will print out the missing values between the "j's":

```
j=11
101
j=111
1001
j=1111
10001
j=10101
```

Consider redoing your `for` statement with a `while`:

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
    j=next(pal_gen)
    digits=0    
    while digits<5:  
        print('j={}'.format(j))
        digits = len(str(j))
        j = pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
    else:
        pal_gen.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. https://stackabuse.com/python-generators/ also says send() also consumes one value, when used without parameter, send() is actually equivalent to next().